# Is it proper to insert key using "_id" in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, insert, pymongo, database

I am building a database using MongoDB. I found two ways to insert keys in pymongo.

```
r.insert({'id': '1234', 'feats': 'abcd'})
```

and

```
r.insert({'_id': '1234', 'feats': 'abcd'})
```

The results in MongoDB are as follows:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51c27f8737450f1d517c1ec4"), 
"id" : "1234", 
"feats" : "abcd"}
```

and

```
{ "_id" : "1234"), 
"feats" : "abcd" }
```

Since not much experienced with MongoDB, I have no idea of the usage about **'_id'**. I think the second way to insert in MongoDB is more simple by now. May it cause other disasters in the future? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mongodb uses _id not id for its unique key

If you choose to add a field called 'id' it is no different from adding a field called 'name'

You can create your own '_id' field but it is usually better to let mongodb generate its own ObjectId rather than you creating your own. see [monogo docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/)

Answer (score 2):

You can also consider as (similar) Identity column in SQL SERVER , it is will become the primary key. But you can have your own key also. For example if you are making a User collection where User Id will be email id and need to be unique , you can put the email as _id and we do not need to create any sepearate index for _id column

Answer (score 0):

`_id` is basically the primary key, by default being populated by an `OjbectId`, however, changable to store any value; bare in mind that it is immutable for updating, essentially once set it cannot be changed.